# Iteration Illegalstate exeption when comparing lists

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Im trying to get the similar items in an arraylist through the use of iterators.
I keep running into this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(ArrayList.java:872)
at com.fryslan.updater.wrappers.MethodDataItem.getIntListSimilarities(MethodDataItem.java:97)
at com.fryslan.updater.wrappers.MethodDataItem.matchAbstractNodes(MethodDataItem.java:67)
at com.fryslan.updater.wrappers.MethodDataItem.equals(MethodDataItem.java:182)
at com.fryslan.updater.Updater.<init>(Updater.java:57)
at com.fryslan.updater.Updater.main(Updater.java:99)
```

The code I'm using is this:

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> getIntListSimilarities(ArrayList<Integer> base, ArrayList<Integer> target) {

    ArrayList<Integer> matching = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator baseIterator = base.listIterator();
    Iterator targetIterator = target.listIterator();

    while (baseIterator.hasNext()) {
        while (targetIterator.hasNext()) {

            int bv = (int) baseIterator.next();
            int tv = (int) targetIterator.next();

            if (bv == tv) {
                matching.add(bv);
                baseIterator.remove();
                targetIterator.remove();
                baseIterator = base.listIterator();
                targetIterator = target.listIterator();
            }
        }
    }

    return matching;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has many problems. For instance, if the inputs are [1] and [1,2], it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`:

```
baseIterator.remove(); // remove the element from ArrayList<Integer> base
...
baseIterator = base.listIterator(); // new Iterator from the base that had its element removed
...
while (targetIterator.hasNext()); // looking at the 2nd Integer in [1,2]
...
int bv = (int) baseIterator.next(); // NoSuchElementException
```

Also, your code might go into an infinite loop if `base` has more elements than `target` (first loop is always `true` and second one is always `false` when looking at `base`'s last element).

Here, the `IllegalStateException` might be because you are calling `remove` on an empty `ArrayList`, however I could not reproduce the problem.

---

If you can't fix your codes with this hint, I'll add a solution.

**Hint**: Merge your two loops into one, evaluate the 2 conditions `hasNext` at the same time in a single `while` loop.

Comment: ofcourse thats it! I'm not realy familar with iterations so i handled it like for loops.
merging the hasNexts fixed it. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job.

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> getIntListSimilarities(ArrayList<Integer> base, ArrayList<Integer> target) {

    ArrayList<Integer> matching = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator baseIterator = base.listIterator();
    Iterator targetIterator = target.listIterator();

    while (baseIterator.hasNext() && targetIterator.hasNext()) {

        int bv = (int) baseIterator.next();
        int tv = (int) targetIterator.next();

        if (bv == tv) {
            matching.add(bv);
            baseIterator.remove();
            targetIterator.remove();
        }
    }

    return matching;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the common elements of two `List<Integer>` without using iterators. The `IllegalStateException` may be thrown because you are **resetting the iterators while iterating** with the lines

```
baseIterator = base.listIterator();
targetIterator = target.listIterator();
```

I don't really see any sense in doing so.

Here is an example of how to find the common elements of two lists, it **requires Java 8**:

```
public static List<Integer> getCommonElementsOf(List<Integer> firstList, List<Integer> secondList) {
    List<Integer> commonElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    firstList.forEach(element -> {
        if (secondList.contains(element)) {
            commonElements.add(element);
        }
    });

    return commonElements;
}
```

This can be done using classic loops, too.